# interaction of permanet magnetic field with electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am working on non contact breaking system for a rotating permanent magnet in an electromagnetic field.so I would like to know if the interaction between the magnetic field and an electromagnet will provide a drag force to stop the motion of the rotating disk in a set up given below 
[image]

Comment: That's going to be a hard one to answer just because accurately modeling the interaction of bar magnets in general is nontrivial. (There's a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets) on it.) It is likely that the permanent magnets would induce some AC currents in the electromagnets and possibly vice-versa which would indeed tend to slow down the disc. However, those are likely to be second-order effects, and probably the net "slow-down" force for one magnet is roughly cancelled out by a "speed-up" with the next one.

Comment: A better system would be metal pads which slid in radially to overlap the disk magnets. It's called a magnetic braking system. It uses Lenz's law.

Comment: @ Bill N using a metal disk would create the eddy current in the disk and the eddy current generates a drag force but the eddy current is directly proportional to the angular velocity of the disk i.e the drag force decrease exponentially and it will never stop the disk thus why i have resorted to use permanent magnets